# Launching Multiple Queries With Bash Script

Tags: bash, curl, http

I have the following bash script ([on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136022/script-to-get-the-http-status-code-of-a-list-of-urls)):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
  curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} $LINE\n" "$LINE"
done < infile > outfile
```

infile:

```
google.com
facebook.com
```

outfile:

```
301 amazon.com
302 facebook.com
```

**Problem:** It is very slow since it verifies line by line.

**Tests:** I have already tried other alternatives, such as [fping](https://superuser.com/questions/1456225/debug-http-status-code-of-a-big-urls-list) (very limited given the size of the list), [pyfunceble](https://github.com/funilrys/PyFunceble) (freezes), [wget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358157/8747573), [GNU parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973891/8747573), etc, etc. None has convinced me. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22379949/8747573) is a solution with xargs, but the output is different from the original script

**Question:** How can I launch multiple queries (parallel processing) with this script so that I could process many lines at the same time (if it would be possible to set the number of lines to be processed manually, avoiding freeze or blocking the script or PC)?

**Update:** Solved!. Thanks

```
cat infile | xargs -I {} -P3 curl {} -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} {}\n" > outfile
```

PD: "-P 3" number of instances

Comment: Probably helpful: [correct xargs parallel usage](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/197192) and [parallel processing using xargs](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/291108) and [similar questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+xargs+parallel).

Comment: @Kusalananda very interesting. checking. thk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P (output from parallel jobs in `xargs` risks being mixed), I would use GNU Parallel instead:

```
cat infile |
  parallel -P0 -q curl {} -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} {}\n" > outfile
```

In this particular case it may be safe to use `xargs` because the output is so short, so the problem with using `xargs` is rather that if someone later changes the code to do something bigger, it will no longer be safe. Or if someone reads this question and thinks he can replace `curl` with something else, then that may also not be safe.

This may be faster:

```
doit() {
  while read LINE; do
    curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} $LINE\n" "$LINE"
  done
}
export -f doit
parallel -j0 --pipepart -a infile --block -10 doit > outfile
```

Comment: I did not know that information, although it does not apply to my case (I work with domains with a limit of 63 compatible IDN characters). I worked in the past with 'parallel' and it consumes too much and it is not as fast as xargs (you can always make a sort -u). Additionally I replaced 'curl' with 'host', since I'm only interested in verifying if the domain exists ('curl + http_code' work with HTTP (S) or FTP (s) and if the domain is active on another port, curl doesn't detects, therefore they are inefficient for my purposes). Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

you could split up your url list in e.g. 10 parts and use a main script ala

```
./subscript1.sh &
./subscript2.sh &
...
./subscript10.sh &
```

to run it in parallel. Caution: They should use distinct log files.