# Bash to launching multiple queries with Xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I would like something similar [to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538340/launching-multiple-queries-with-bash-script):

```
cat infile | xargs -I {} -P3 curl {} -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} {}\n" > outfile
```

but with this script (that is, include xargs to launch multiple queries):

```
for ip in `cat infile`; do
    for sub in "" "www." "ftp."; do
            host -t a "${sub}${ip}";
    done
done | grep address | awk '{ print $4 }' > out
```

infile:

```
google.com
facebook.com
```

outfile:

```
172.217.172.14
172.217.30.196
157.240.6.35
31.13.67.35
```

Comment: Please would you [edit] your question to include an example of the desired output from your example input

Comment: @roaima add outfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with xargs you can call bash to do what you want

```
cat infile \
     | xargs -I {} -P3  bash -c 'for sub in "" "www." "ftp."; do host -t a "${sub}{}" ; done '
```

On top of this command you can add what you want

```
cat infile \
     | xargs -I {} -P3  bash -c 'for sub in "" "www." "ftp."; do host -t a "${sub}{}" ; done '  \
     | MY_POWER_FULL_SED_OR_GREP
```

or if you want to add the grep into the bash command

```
cat infile \
     | xargs -I {} -P3  bash -c 'for sub in "" "www." "ftp."; do host -t a "${sub}{}" ; done | MY_POWER_FULL_SED_OR_GREP '
```

Comment: almost. but need included last part | grep address | awk '{ print $4 }' >

Comment: i modified my answer